# WebView in MAUI inline HTML cannot access local resources

Tags: webview, maui

On MAUI WebView I am loading an inline HTML like this:

```
string HTMLPicture = @<html style="height: 100%;"><head><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=0.1"><title>picture</title></head><body style="margin: 0px; background: black;">  <img style="object-fit: contain" src="file:///G:\files/aladdin.jpg" width="100%" height="100%"></body></html>

webView.Source = new HtmlWebViewSource
    {
        Html = HTMLPicture 
    };
```

The page load but the `img` fails to retrieve the graphic file.

If I put the html in a file (for ex. "page.html") and load it as `URLWebViewSource` instead the picture is displayed correctly.

Is this a security mechanism that inline html cannot access local file resources?

(I am currently first testing this on Windows before adapting file paths for Android)

Comment: Have you tried ```"file:///G:/files/aladdin.jpg"```?